# How to fix the starting up problem with two operation system?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have installed Ubuntu & Windows 10 on my laptop in different drives.

But when I start up my laptop. The option to choose system Win 10 always failed.

I could only use "F12" to start Windows boot manager to open the windows 10 system.

What's wrong with this issue? How to fix that?>

Comment: Welcome to Ask U+buntu!  **;-)** Do you have an EFI or a BIOS-based system?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My laptop was in windows 10 system originally. And I add the ubuntu system using USB-drive with EFI.

Comment: "But when I start up my laptop. The option to choose system Win 10 always failed." can you tell if this is from the grub bootloader?

Comment: Yes, it's from grub bootloader

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what computer brand you are using, but instead of hitting F12 for boot options try using F2 (or what ever option gets you into CMOS) and right arrow over to the "boot" tab. Here you can choose which drive to boot from (the Linux drive or the Windows Drive). Select the drive you want to boot from, hit F10 to save changes and reboot. 
Also try installing all updates on the Linux side. 
Worst case you may need to modify the boot manager. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: No problem, I always use the CMOS to select / change the primary HDD instead of using the F12 option. There are some online tutorials that will walk you through modifying your boot manager software if you have one installed for dual boot. Here is a starting point. http://www.thefreecountry.com/utilities/multi-boot-managers.shtml